# Well-definedness of pointwise addition of hyperreals

Tags: set-theory, filters, nonstandard-analysis

I'm reading [An Introduction to Nonstandard Analysis by Isaac Davis](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Davis.pdf), and I'm confused on one of the lemma inside which helps to prove that the set of hyperreals form a field. Note that $\mathcal{U}$ here represents an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.

> **Lemma 2.5.** Pointwise addition and multiplication are well-defined binary operations on the set of real-valued sequences under ultrafilter equivalence.
>
> *Proof*. Suppose that $a_1 =_\mathcal{U} a_2$ and $b_1 =_\mathcal{U} b_2$. This means that $[[a_1 = a_2]] \in \mathcal{U}$ and $[[b_1 = b_2]] \in \mathcal{U}$, so by the finite intersection property we know that $[[a_1 = a_2]] \cap [[b_1 = b_2]] = \{j \in \mathbb{N} \mid a_1 = a_2 \text{ & } b_1 = b_2\} \in \mathcal{U}$. **But the set on which both $a_1$ and $a_2$ agree and $b_1$ and $b_2$ agree is the same set on which $a_1 + b_1$ and $a_2 + b_2$ agree.** That is, $\{j \in \mathbb{N} \mid a_1 = a_2 \text{ & } b_1 = b_2\} = [[a_1 + b_1 = a_2 + b_2]] \in \mathcal{U}$. Therefore $a_1 + b_1 =_\mathcal{U} a_2 + b_2$, so addition is well-defined. An analagous proof follows for multiplication.

My confusion lies in the bolded statement. I agree that $\{j \in \mathbb{N} \mid a_1 = a_2 \text{ & } b_1 = b_2\} \subseteq [[a_1 + b_1 = a_2 + b_2]]$ but not the converse. A counterexample I thought of is this:
\begin{align*}
a_1 = b_1 &= (1,0,0,0,\dots) \\
a_2 = b_2 &= (-1,0,0,0.\dots) \\
\end{align*}
In this case, we have $[[a_1 = a_2]] = [[b_1 = b_2]] = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\} \implies [[a_1 = a_2]] \cap [[b_1 = b_2]] = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, but $[[a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2]] = \mathbb{N}$.

What is my error in reasoning here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're correct**, that statement is wrong. The right statement is that the set of indices on which $a_1+b_1$ and $a_2+b_2$ agree *contains* the set of indices on which $a_1$ and $a_2$ agree and on which $b_1$ and $b_2$ agree. This is enough to get the desired result:

- The second set is an intersection of two sets in the ultrafilter, so is in the ultrafilter.
- The first set contains a set in the ultrafilter, so is in the ultrafilter.

*(Note that we haven't used the complement property of ultrafilters - the argument here applies more generally to arbitrary [reduced products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_product).)*